# What makes the flowers glow?

Tags: plant-physiology, flowers

[image][image]

I had learnt in a plant biology course that, all the flowers are actually originating from leaves, with several mutations. I wonder what makes a flower sparkly like this.

Photos belong to a Phalaenopsis Orchid (White) (under direct sunlight) . But I believe this can be observed in many plants.

When searched for it, I saw one explanation on that they shine right after they are watered. But I observed this long after the plant was watered. So I guess this is not the case.

Also I've read about the pigments that absorbs different wavelenghts and give the plant its color. But I couldn't find an explanation about this sparkling view.

Another thing I read was about the shiny views of some flowers, like buttercup flower. It is said that this is originating from flat cell shapes. (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC5332578/). But again, this is different than what I am asking.

Biology is not my major (probably as you have already guessed :)), so I might not be searching it with the right keywords. So I will be glad to get some help. Thank you :)!

Edit:

Another photo, taken with flash light. The shiny view is only in the side leaves (petals and sepals), not in the middle parts.

[image]

Comment: hi new user and welcome! please provide name of the flower, and also any research you did to asnwer this question yourself

Comment: Hi, sure. Actually photo was just an example, I observe this in many flowers. Still, I will edit my question. Thank you :)

Comment: Also what lighting conditions &c.  From a quick look, the "sparkles" look like they might be small drops of water.  Have you looked at them under a microscope?

Comment: There was a strong sunlight on them. I don't have a microscope :). So do you mean water droplets due to the air humidity ?

Comment: I'm not sure of the conditions in which the photograph was taken. That could be anything from wax on the leaf, or stomata.

Comment: I am adding a photo taken with a flash light. You can see that the shining part is only the petals (and sepals) not the middle part.

Comment: @GabrielFair this is something you can see with your naked eye in direct sunlight on daffodil petals as well as iris petals. I'm sure you can see it on many others but those are places I have seen flowers sparkle like this.

Comment: Could be water condensing from the air (dew), or it could be water released from the plants via transpiration: https://water.usgs.gov/edu/watercycletranspiration.html  But I'm just guessing...  Though Google Images has some similar pictures: https://www.google.com/search?q=water+droplets+on+leaves+from+transpiration&complete=0&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi2u7iBu8ngAhUBqp4KHTVgBp8Q_AUIDigB&biw=1223&bih=952

Comment: @L.B. Yes it is exactly what I am talking about. I had thought that this was a very wellknown phenomenna through.

Comment: @jamesqf As you had Said, that sparkles really look like tiny water droplets (nearly microscopic). Actually they more look to me like some cyrstals, like a snow surface.  I have looked those transpiration photos. I couldn't catch a simular image though.. Those droplets are very big and seems to be at the surface of the leaf. Mine seems like they are at the inner tissue. It might be because they are very small scaled. I also searched it as "petal transpiration" but couldn't find a simular image yet.

Comment: @jamesqf - I knew this was an orchid when I saw the first picture. It is not water. It has to do with surface cell shape, translucency and light. It's not an uncommon phenomenon in flowers.

Comment: @anongoodnurse hi, as far as I understood from the article I mentioned in the question the flat cell shapes provides a mirror like or buttered/polished like shiny surface.But here, I think we can see some obvious particles. Might they be some **plant mineral crystals**? I had also thought of dust particles but these particles are very homogeneous and can be seen also at the back side of the petals, which I wouldn't expect to hold much dust.

Comment: @user6069929: I was thinking of this image in particular: https://image.shutterstock.com/image-photo/close-water-drops-on-pumpkin-450w-1027095193.jpg Looks almost exactly like yours.  But try some experiments, like brushing the surface of the leaf/flower, or passing a razor blade over it.

Comment: @user6069929 - I don't think so. See http://bulbnrose.x10.mx/Heredity/KayPetals1981/KayPetals1981.html; look at the photomicrographs. Especially helpful are scanning electron micrographs of orchid petals.

Comment: @jamesqf I see. Mine are not even that obvious. Moreover they are independent of the temperature or the time of the day. Also when I tap on the surface with my finger, it doesn't give a wet feeling neighter the pattern is distrubbed. But okay I will try those :) Thank you.

Comment: @anongoodnurse Thank you for the source. I have skimmed it, I couldn't catch the SEM Photos of Orchids (might be as I am not familiar with the names.., I couldn't Google it all). But, i.e. the one with conical cells which the light is reflected only from the tips and generates a spotted-like pattern. There it's written that the photo is in x160 scale. Mine are visible with bare eye. What would you say on that?

Comment: I have seen the phenomenon you describe to some degree in many flowers: violets, daffodils, but most prominently (in my mind) on orchids. Look up "scanning Electrom micrographs orchid petals; with what the paper discussed, it should correlate.